# What does this regular expression do?

Tags: regex

What does the following regular expression do?

```
^\d{1,2}(\-|\/|\.)\d{1,2}\1\d{4}$
```

Particularly, what is the purpose of the `\1` part?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#usebackrefinregex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). There's barely anything advanced in there (well except for that `\1` you pointed to):

```
^         # the start of the string
\d        # a digit
{1,2}     # 1 or 2 of those
(         # start the first subpattern, which can later be referred to with \1
  \-      # a literal hyphen (there is no need for escaping, but it doesn't hurt)
|         # or
  \/      # a literal slash
|         # or
  \.      # a literal period
)         # end of subpattern
\d{1,2}   # one or two more digits
\1        # the exact same thing that was matched in the first subpattern. this
          # is called a backreference
\d{4}     # 4 digits
$         # the end of the string
```

I.e. this asserts that the input string contains exactly one date, no more no less, of format `ddmmyyyy` (or could also be `mmddyyyy`), with possible delimiters `.`, `-` or `/` (and consistent delimiter usage). Note that it does not ensure a *correct* date. Months and days could be anything from `00` to `99`.

**Note** that the exact meaning of `\d` depends on the regex engine and culture you are using. *Usually* it means `[0-9]` (any ASCII digit). But for example in .NET it can also mean "any Unicode character that represents a digit".

Answer (score 3):

1. `^` Start of string
2. `\d{1,2}` Matches 1 or 2 digits (0-9)
3. `(\-|\/|\.)` Matches either a "-" **OR** "/" **OR** "."
4. `\d{1,2}` Matches 1 or 2 digits (0-9) again
5. `\1` is a **back-reference.** Matches another instance of the same character captured by the group in No. 3
6. `\d{4}` Matches 4 digits
7. `$` End of string

This would match a date in the following formats. Please note, the `dd`, `mm`, and `yyyy` ranges **are not being checked**, so the date could still be invalid.

```
d-m-yyyy
d/m/yyyy
d.m.yyyy
```

`d` & `m` could be 1 **or** 2 digits each.

Comment: @Bergi Oh crap. The combinations will be twice as many. I'll just mention that. :)

Answer (score 1):

It matches:

- one or two digits
- a dash, slash or period
- one or two digits
- another separator just like the one earlier
- four digits

The `\1` is a back reference to the value matched by the first group, i.e `(\-|\/|\.)`.

For example:

```
2-14-2003
99.99.9999
1/2/0001
```

Comment: smells like a lame date regex